# Teststack.white cannot find Toolstrip item

Tags: automated-tests, white-framework

When I trying to get Toolstrip element

```
ToolStrip toolStrip = StartApplication.Window.Get<ToolStrip>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Toolbar"));`
```

this error occurs :

> error: Failed to get ControlType=tool bar,Name=Toolbar

Toolbar properties are:

> - Name: "Toolbar"
> - ControlType:   UIA_ToolBarControlTypeId (0xC365)
> - LocalizedControlType:  "tool bar"
> - IsEnabled: true
> - IsOffscreen:   false
> - IsKeyboardFocusable:   true
> - HasKeyboardFocus:  true
> - LegacyIAccessible.Name:    "Toolbar"
> - LegacyIAccessible.Role:    tool bar
> - (0x16) LegacyIAccessible.State:    focused,focusable (0x100004)

Comment: It seems that problem is in wrong Control Type, I had the such problem with "pane" control type it was inspected as "pane" but I should use "GroupBox" type for use it with teststack.

Comment: This is a Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbar  How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ByAutomationId` as the search criteria.

As an example:

```
ToolStrip toolStrip = StartApplication.Window.Get<ToolStrip>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("Toolbar"));
```

Comment: the problem is that this element has Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbar  type, i still have no chance to get it. Do you have any idea?